# How can I fix 'request_token must be provided' error when creating an access token in TMDb API?

Tags: reactjs, api, token, project, access-token

Can not get the access token in tmdb api

- first , i got a API Read Access Token (v4 auth) in my account by registering in tmdb
- then , i take a look at `https://developer.themoviedb.org/v4/reference/auth-create-request-token`
- following the guild in here `https://developer.themoviedb.org/v4/docs/authentication-user` , i can get the Request_Token
  {
  "request_token": "..../my-request-token/....",
  "status_code": 1,
  "status_message": "Success.",
  "success": true
  }
- then i locate to this website : `https://www.themoviedb.org/auth/access?request_token={request_token}` , fill it by my request token , and click the button `APPROVE` and redirect me to this website `https://www.themoviedb.org/auth/access/approve` which mean i successed
- for doing 2 step , head to the last one , create access token , on the right side of web page , in the 'Select credentials' feild , i chose Access Token Auth , then i pasted the access token ( the ones in the first line of my describe , that one i been use for getting the request token ) , but the  respond is
  {
  "errors": [
  "request_token must be provided"
  ],
  "success": false
  }
  even though i have the request token and make it approved , please help me get the request-token